# Make request to on-prem service through "transit" vNet

Tags: azure, networking, routes, vnet

I have an Azure vNet A that is peered to the on-prem network. I want to make a TCP request to on-prem service from another vNet B. Is it possible to use vNet A as "transit" network to redirect traffic to the on-prem service? The restriction is vNet B cannot use peering, virtual kubelet doesn't support it.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't use VNET peering try to deploy Virtual Network Gateway in vNetB. Then connect
vNetA and vNetB gateways using VNet-2-VNet connection type.

Comment: If I understand correctly, this suggestion will allow me to make a request from A to B, but not from A to on-prem.

Comment: If configured properly then you will be able to connect:
On-premises <-> vNetA <-> vNetB
For connections between on-premises and vNetB traffic will be routed through vNetA Virtual Network Gateway.